# How to upload multiple files using play framework 2.6 WsClient?

Tags: scala, file-upload, playframework, akka-stream, ws-client

This is the code for uploading **Single file** in as Play Documentation.
Any Idea for Multiple Files?

ws.url(url)
.post(Source(FilePart("hello", "hello.txt", Option("text/plain"), FileIO.fromPath(tmpFile.toPath)) :: DataPart("key", "value") :: List()))

Comment: It depends - does your URL accept an array of data POSTed? If not, you will have to loop through each file you want to upload and do it one by one.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley - yes, it accepts multiple files, I need to upload multiple files at once, any other solution without using iteration or different rest client that I can use?